# How to save an image generated by gwt canvas, to computer hard disk?

Tags: gwt, canvas

Below is the code to get image from canvas in GWT.

```
testCanvas.setWidth(144 + "px");
testCanvas.setHeight(144 + "px");
testCanvas.setCoordinateSpaceWidth(144);
testCanvas.setCoordinateSpaceHeight(144);
context = testCanvas.getContext2d();
context.fillRect(1,1,114,114);      
imagelocation=testCanvas.toDataUrl();
Image image=new Image(imagelocation);
```

Now I have the image and I want to save this image on some location in my computer. How can I do that?

Comment: You mean you want to trigger a file download dialog box for that image?

Answer (score 1):

You can use canvas.toDataUrl("image/png") to save the image.

```
// Add screen capture button
Button bt = new Button();
bt.setText("Capture");
RootPanel.get().add(bt);
bt.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
        Window.open(canvas.toDataUrl("image/png"), "_blank", "");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll have to either send the data to a server and have the user download the data from that server, or embed some Flash or Java object that can access the hard drive directly. JavaScript (including GWT) is not allowed to write files to the hard drive in most browsers.

If you just need the image to be accessible to your application, you could use some form of local storage other than files, though your user wouldn't be able to access that from other applications.